# Very extremely weird IIS\Reporting Services permission issue

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2012, ssrs, iis-8

Server 2012 Standard
Reporting Services 2012

I have 2 URLs for my Reporting Services:

```
http://MACHINE-NAME/reportserver

https://domain.com/reportserver
```

When using the local url locally everything works fine.
When using the external url externally everything works fine.
When using the external url locally (from the machine itself) I get a user\pass prompt but doesnt matter what I type in it simply WILL NOT go through.

What am I missing here?

Comment: One weird thing I found out though.
Altering rssreportserver.config
removing ntlm and adding basic login instead solved this issue...although my application could not use reporting services anymore.
I suppose this is a kerebros issue now.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!

http://thetazblog.taznetworks.com/2006/03/crm-30-sbe-sql-reporting-error.html

This is how to disable Loopback on Reporting Services.